# I tried implementing server-side rendering, but broke my API in the process

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I have very basic application at the moment that I wanted to try to implement SSR with.

### problem 1

Previously I would send index.html (that had a script tag with my bundle.js inside) to requests made to '/' and that would render on the client.

Now I'm rendering the app on the server for every request made to '/' and now, expectantly, when I make GET requests to '/api/users/' my isomorphic rendering function is executed (even though this is an API request and should not be rendering anything).

I understand why, because of where I placed this function in the middleware is such that all requests made to the app will run that middleware.

My question is: How can I ignore this function unless a browser is requesting it? Is that even the right question? It sounds like I'm asking for a hack, which means I'm misunderstanding something.

### problem 2

This is the cause of another problem I am having when the client requests bundle.js. Because each request is rendering the app and sending html back, requests to get the bundle are receiving an HTML response, which when parsed by the browser errors out as expected (Unexpected token '<').

I think I've designed my server poorly, and maybe someone can give me some insight or point me to a good place to start learning.

server.js

```
require('babel-register')
var express = require('express')
// TODO setup global error handling
var path = require('path') // built-in middleware
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

const isomorphic = require('./isomorphic')

// change promise library of mongoose to bluebird
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird')

// create the api and auth
var api = require('./api/api')
var auth = require('./auth/routes')

// make app
var app = express()

// setup the app middleware
require('./middleware/appMiddleware')(app)

// get the api and auth
app.use('/api', api)
app.use('/auth', auth)

// serve static assets
app.use(express.static('dist'))

// serverside rendering
app.use(isomorphic)

// give the bundle
// app.get('/dist/bundle.js', function(req, res) {
//   res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/bundle.js'), function(err) {
//     if (err) {
//       res.status(500).send(err)
//     }
//   })
// })

module.exports = app
```

Note `app.get('/dist/bundle.js', function...` is commented out because I believe `app.use(express.static('dist))` should be handling that. Right?

isomorphic.js

```
var React = require('react')
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server')
var StaticRouter = require('react-router-dom').StaticRouter
var ServerStyleSheet = require('styled-components').ServerStyleSheet
var fs = require('fs')
var _ = require('lodash')
var baseTemplate = fs.readFileSync('./index.html') // TODO change to async function maybe
var template = _.template(baseTemplate)
var sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
var something = sheet.collectStyles(App)
var css = sheet.getStyleTags()
var App = require('../src/js/App').default

const isomorphic = (req, res) => {
  var context = {}
  var body = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    React.createElement(StaticRouter, { location: req.url, context },
      React.createElement(App)
    )
  )

  console.log('hello?');

  if (context.url) {
    // TODO if there is a redirect
  }

  res.write(template({body: body}))
  res.end()
}

module.exports = isomorphic
```

Please let me know if you need to see any other files.

### update 1

I added a check in isomorphic.js that looks like this:

```
if (req.url !== '/') {
    next()
} else {
    ...
}
```

And I uncommented the `app.get('/dist/bundle.js')` code.

Now everything seems to be half working, however:

That if check seems to be bad practice because the user could request routes that exist on the client that are not the root.

React's server render does match the checksum on the client, therefore negating the SSR.

And the `app.use(express.static('dist'))` appears to be doing absolutely nothing. The `'dist'` directory is one level up from my server.js file, so I've changed it to `'../dist'` but it still 404s (with that `.get` commented).

### update 2

I have figured out why `express.static('dist')` was not working.

One, I changed it from `express.static('dist')` to `express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/'))` to be sure it going to the correct path.

Two, in my index.html, the script tag was originally

```
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

when apparently it should have been this (I got lucky and guessed this could have been the issue)

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should mount isomorphic to a route, maybe '/'. Currently, you're doing app.use(isomorphic), which calls isomorphic for all requests.

Comment: Or, you can just check req.url, and if it is one of those you want to ignore, you can just call next, so that isomorphic part of the code is not run. Although, in this case you'll have to put it above your route configuration.

Comment: Mounting to '/' doesn't change the behavior unfortunately. Leaving the '/' out is the same as putting in (at least that's what it is behaving like for me).

Comment: Your should check value of req.url inside your isomorphic middleware, and call next for the urls you want to ignore.

Comment: Strangely, calling `next()` even on the first line of the isomorphic function with the new signature `const isomorphic = (req, res, next) =>` doesn't change anything. If I move `app.use(isomorphic)` above the api and auth routes, `GET /users/` returns the app in HTML and not user data.